# Confusion with if(something){} and if(something == true){}

Tags: c#, if-statement

I sometimes see people on youtube writing just

```
if(something) { ...; }
```

instead of

```
if(something == true) { ...; }
```

What is the rule for using if-statement like this? Is it because if-statement by default check if something is true?

Comment: `if` statement always checks if the expression inside it is true. and by default, if something is not 0, null or false, then it is true.

Comment: @Banana This is C#. Only `true` is true.

Answer (score 6):

It is just for checking if the condition between parenthesis is true or false.

`if(something == true) {}`

is in most cases the same as, read below why I used the word `most`.

`if(something) {}`

I personally don't think adding `== true` makes it more readable. So I tend to use `if(something)`. I would pick the one that is used by your team. Programming alone? Pick the one you like the most.

As additon: when checking if the condition is false, you could use:

`if(!something) {}`

Note:

From die maus' answer:

> While Max answer is correct, i would like to add something. While if
>   (booleanVariable == true) and if (booleanVariable) are generally the
>   exact same thing, you are not taking into consideration Nullable
>   or bool? for shorthand.

Comment: Not when something is a `bool?`

Comment: @HenkHolterman You are right, as I commented on @die maus' answer, you do need `== true` when checking on a nullable bool. Otherwise it would result in a syntax error.

Comment: Comments don't count, your answer still reads "is the same as" ... Worthy of a downvote.

Answer (score 4):

For `bool` values it's the same... But note that:

```
// Note the name of the class (Nomen est omen)
public class InsaneClass
{
    public static implicit operator bool(InsaneClass v)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Operator bool");
        return true;
    }

    public static bool operator==(InsaneClass v1, bool v2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Operator ==");
        return true;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(InsaneClass v1, bool v2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Operator !=");
        return true;
    }
}
```

and then

```
var ic = new InsaneClass();

if (ic)
{
    // Operator bool
}

if (ic == true)
{
    // Operator ==
}
```

:-)

But then, normally you shouldn't overload the `implicit operator bool`, unless you really know what you are doing! (note that you can obtain other interesting results by overloading the `operator true` plus the `implicit operator InsaneClass(bool)` and the `operator==(InsaneClass, InsaneClass)`)... This shows that *there is* at least a reason why Java doesn't have operator overloading :-)

Comment: You can also get this behavior by overloading the [true](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d.aspx) and [false](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6292hy1k.aspx) operators.

Comment: @Kyle Yep... and in fact there is a note `note that you can obtain other interesting results by overloading the operator true`

Comment: Considering overloaded operators is way over the top here.

Answer (score 4):

While Max answer is correct, i would like to add something.
While `if (booleanVariable == true)` and `if (booleanVariable)` are generally the exact same thing, you are not taking into consideration `Nullable<bool>` or `bool?` for shorthand.

Consider this:

```
var nb = (bool?)true;
```

Then:

```
if (nb) // this is a syntax error
{
    // [...]
}
```

Whereas:

```
if (nb == true) // this is a NOT an error.
{
    // [...]
}
```

Nullable bools are not the most common thing to encounter however.

As a general rule, just write `if (booleanValue)`, since it looks cleaner.
Works the same for everything that returns a boolean value.

`if (book.HasPages())` is more readable than `if (book.HasPages() == true)` in my book *(no pun intended)*

Comment: addition of value in my opinion:)

Answer (score 1):

Given that something is of type bool and not some type with an implicit conversion to bool, then the result of both will be the same the if statement is made up of at least two parts

- a condition
- the body to be executed if the condition is met (aka evaluates to true

in your first example the condition is a simple expression namely `something` so if something is true then the body of the if statement is executed.

In your second example the expression is slightly longer `something == true` which is a binary comparison. It will check if the values on either side are equal in which case it evaluates to `true` and if they are not evaluates to `false` if we write that out

- When something is true the expression is `true == true` and evaluates to true
- When something is false the expression is `false == true` and evaluates to false

In other words the longer expression will always evaluate to the value of `something` but it uses a redundant comparison to get to the result.